AWS CDK Testing: Match array items in any order
I'm trying to test creation of an IAM Policy in AWS CDK. Currently, I have
template.has_resource_properties("AWS::IAM::Policy", {
    "PolicyDocument": {
        "Statement": [{
            "Action": assertions.Match.array_with([
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            ]),
            "Effect": "Allow",
          },
          {
            "Action": assertions.Match.array_with([
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ]),
            "Effect": "Allow",
            }
        ],}})

which fails, because the items in "Action" lists aren't in that order. I've read that some combination of Match.object_like and Match.array_with may work, but re-formatting as
"Statement": [{
     "Action": assertions.Match.array_with(
                assertions.Match.object_like([
                  "s3:ListBucket",
                 "s3:GetBucketLocation",
               ])
      ),
      "Effect": "Allow",
  },

fail because the argument of Match.object_like is not an object.
What is the best way to match items in an array in any order?

Can't do it with assertions - capture the values of the arrays into a new Capture() and then assert the array contents via any method you like (e.g. converting to a Set).

Based on gshpychka's answer, here's the working test I came up with:
bucketCapture = assertions.Capture()
objectCapture = assertions.Capture()
template.has_resource_properties(
    "AWS::IAM::Policy",
    {
        "PolicyDocument": {
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Action": bucketCapture,
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                },
                {
                    "Action": objectCapture,
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                },
            ],
        }
    },
)

expectedBucketCapture = ["s3:ListBucket", "s3:GetBucketLocation"]
expectedObjectCapture = [
    "s3:PutObject",
    "s3:GetObject",
    "s3:PutObjectAcl",
    "s3:GetObjectAcl",
    "s3:DeleteObject",
]

bucketDifference = set(bucketCapture.as_array()) ^ set(expectedBucketCapture)
assert not bucketDifference

objectDifference = set(objectCapture.as_array()) ^ set(expectedObjectCapture)
assert not objectDifference

